# Setting Javascript Date On Server With Offset

Tags: javascript

I am running a Meteor application and have an API on my server that is going out and getting RSS feeds and timestamps them using new Date(). I have no way of setting the time on the server, so it defaults to GMT.

Is there a way to use new Date() with an offset so it saves the date as Central Standard Time?

The reason for this need is because when I display the posts by day on my site, it is completely off because the timestamps are GMT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timestamps are and should be always in UTC. There is no reason to change that. Instead, change the code that displays them wrongly.

Comment: JS uses universal timestamp and client's timezone to convert time to a human readable format. So you don't need to do anything.